# Is there a way to return/print list item without quotes or brackets?

Tags: python

Sorry if this is already mentioned somewhere(I couldn't find it).

I basically want to list an item from a list but its including quotes and brackets(which I don't want).
Here's my data:

```
inputData = {'red':3, 'blue':1, 'green':2, 'organge':5}
```

Here's my class to find items either based on key or value.

```
class Lookup(dict):
    """
    a dictionary which can lookup value by key, or keys by value
    """
    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        """items can be a list of pair_lists or a dictionary"""
        dict.__init__(self, items)

    def get_key(self, value):
        """find the key(s) as a list given a value"""
        return [item[0] for item in self.items() if item[1] == value]

    def get_value(self, key):
        """find the value given a key"""
        return self[key]
```

it works fine except for the brackets.

```
print Lookup().get_key(2) # ['blue']  but I want it to just output blue
```

I know I can do this via replacing the bracket/quotes( `LookupVariable.replace("'", "")` ) but I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
return [item[0] for item in self.items() if item[1] == value]
```

to

```
return next(item[0] for item in self.items() if item[1] == value)
```

Right now you're returning the result of a list comprehension -- a `list`. Instead, you want to return the first item returned by the equivalent generator expression -- that's what `next` does.

**Edit:** If you actually want multiple items, use Greg's answer -- but it sounds to me like you're only thinking about getting a single key -- this is a good way to do that.

If you want it to raise a `StopIteration` error if the value doesn't exist, leave it as above. If you want it to return something else instead (like `None`) do:

```
return next((item[0] for item in self.items() if item[1] == value), None)
```

Comment: I think the idea is that `get_key()` can legitimately return more than one item.

Comment: @Greg Sounds to me like he wants only one key. `print Lookup.get_key(10)[0]` (assuming he means an instance of `Lookup` and not the class) will give an `IndexError`, while with `next` lets you handle the "no result" case internally.

Comment: thanks that worked also.  In in the interest of learning, can I clarify?  I understand Greg's answer but did you add the 'next' to it because its returning the entire list first(even if there's only one item in that list) and we are moving to the see solely the next item in the list by using the 'next' command?  Like if there are 2 results in the list, I could keep using next to go through the other items in the list?

Comment: @Lostsoul that would work, but this version just returns the first item, if you wanted the whole list, then just return it and `join` it or iterate over it in a `for` loop, and Python will automatically call `next` internally to do that iteration -- if you want the whole thing, there is no reason to call it yourself.

Comment: I get it now..thanks agf.  You helped me yesterday as well, Thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the returned *list* value, which Python formats with brackets and quotes. To print just the first element from the list:

```
print Lookup.get_key(2)[0]
```

To print the elements of the list separated by commas:

```
print ", ".join(str(x) for x in Lookup.get_key(2))
```

or

```
print ", ".join(map(str, Lookup.get_key(2)))
```

Comment: omg..thank you so much.  I didn't realize that it was just printing a list and I could select the items.  I'm a bit new to python(and newer to lists/dicts) so I thought that was just the way python printed them.  Many thanks Greg(also..awesome hairdue in your pic).